# MDX Combining Queries

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I am new to MDX and am attempting to combine 2 separate queries into the format of:

**|Product Name|Quantity Madison_Chicago|Quantity Chicago_Madison|**

I have my two individual queries which create each criteria for the Quantity listed below:

```
------Query #1------
WITH
   MEMBER measures.Quantity_Madison_Chicago as 'COALESCEEMPTY( [Measures]. 
   [Quantity - Tb Transactions], 0)' 
SELECT {
    measures.Quantity_Madison_Chicago
} ON COLUMNS,
  {(
    [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS
  )} ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT ({
    [Tb Consumer].[City].&[Chicago]
  }) ON COLUMNS
FROM (  
  SELECT ({ 
    [Tb Supplier].[City].&[Madison]
  }) ON COLUMNS
FROM [DS715]))

------Query #2------
WITH
   MEMBER measures.Quantity_Chicago_Madison as 'COALESCEEMPTY( [Measures]. 
   [Quantity - Tb Transactions], 0)'
SELECT {
   measures.Quantity_Chicago_Madison
} ON COLUMNS,
{(
    [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS
)} ON ROWS
FROM (
   SELECT ({
     [Tb Consumer].[City].&[Madison]
}) ON COLUMNS
FROM (
   SELECT ({
     [Tb Supplier].[City].&[Chicago]
}) ON COLUMNS
FROM [DS715]))
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two calculated members:

```
WITH  
MEMBER measures.Quantity_Madison_Chicago 
  CASE WHEN
      [Tb Consumer].[City].currentMember=[Tb Consumer].[City].&[Chicago]
         AND
      [Tb Supplier].[City].currentMember=[Tb Supplier].[City].&[Madison]
THEN COALESCEEMPTY( [Measures]. 
   [Quantity - Tb Transactions], 0)
ELSE 0
END

MEMBER measures.Quantity_Chicago_Madison AS
  CASE WHEN
      [Tb Consumer].[City].currentMember=[Tb Consumer].[City].&[Madison]
         AND
      [Tb Supplier].[City].currentMember=[Tb Supplier].[City].&[Chicago]
THEN COALESCEEMPTY( [Measures]. 
   [Quantity - Tb Transactions], 0)
ELSE 0
END


SELECT {
   measures.Quantity_Chicago_Madison , measures.Quantity_Madison_Chicago 
} ON COLUMNS,
{  [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS
FROM [DS715]
```

I don't think you will need to slice the cube on supplier/consumer  city in the select in order to work but I don't have SSAS currently to try. If it doesn't work like that do the select as you have done using the 2 calculated members and adding both cities in consumer and supplier dimensions subselects

Comment: I've been working with the query listed above, but it doesn't yield the exact results I need. I was thinking if I added one of the calculated measures to ROWS, that may get the correct counts I am looking for, but I keep getting an error of 'Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function.', do you have any suggestions for doing this type of selection?

Comment: You cannot add different dimensions/measures in the same axis without crossjoining. That's why you get that error. It's the same as with two dimensions on Rows - if you add them with comma you get that error that's why you use a * and cross join them so it can work

Comment: It should be in columns. What is wrong with the results of that query? You say they are not exact

Comment: Below is the expected output:-----   
Airplane   | 158 | 0
Auto         | 106 | 225
Boat         | 47   |0
Computer|113  |0
Gas         |5400|0
Milk         |1300|1010
Orange    |2000|725
TV           |160|0          ---------                                                                                                   The output I see is: -------- Airplane   | 1278| 0
Auto         | 5831| 5831
Boat         | 600400   |0
Computer|9413 |0
Gas         |605910|0
Milk         |66980|66980
Orange    |10805|10805
TV           |12600|0 -------

Comment: So the expected output is the result of my two individual queries, so for airplane the counts were 158 for one city pair and 0 for the other city pair. But the counts in the query mentioned above are very high and I'm not sure where it goes wrong

Comment: One other thing I noticed is the total for the measures is equal to '1,313,217' which is the same as the total quantity of the entire table. So it seems the filters applied in the measures is not filtering out records correctly.